# Doctrine: Undefined index when trying to access one-to-many php

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I have Problem with Doctrine. I have two Entities and want to get the one-to-many correalation working.

**User**

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class User
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="role", mappedBy="userId", cascade={"ALL"})
     */
    private $roles;
}
```

**Roles**

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Role
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") 
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="user", inversedBy="roles") 
     * 
     */
     protected $userId;

     /** @Column(type="string") */
     protected $name;
 }
```

But when I try to access the roles of a User:

```
var_dump($user->getRoles()->first()->getName());
```

> **Notice: Undefined index: userId** in /home/ubuntu/workspace/atlas/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php on line 1794 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/atlas/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php on line 1798 string(10) "ROLE_ADMIN" Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ubuntu/workspace/atlas/Controller/LoginController.php on line 15 "

Which means I get the correct value but a few Warnings and I am not sure if I can ignore them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One User** can have **Many Roles**
**One Role** can belong to **Many Users**

So, the association is `ManyToMany`

Your mappings are wrongly defined. Please consider replacing it with this one :

**User**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class User
{
    /** 
     * @Id 
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     */
    protected $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function addRole($role)
    {
        if (this->getRoles()->contains($role)) {
            return;
        } else {
            $this->getRoles()->add($role);
            $role->addUser($this);
        }
    }

    public function removeRole($role)
    {
        if (!this->getRoles()->contains($role)) {
            return;
        } else {
            $this->getRoles()->removeElement($role);
            $role->removeUser($this);
        }
    }
}
```

**Role**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer") 
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles") 
     */
    protected $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser($user)
    {
        if (this->getUsers()->contains($user)) {
            return;
        } else {
            $this->getUsers()->add($user);
            $user->addRole($this);
        }
    }

    public function removeUser($user)
    {
        if (!this->getUsers()->contains($user)) {
            return;
        } else {
            $this->getUsers()->removeElement($user);
            $user->removeRole($this);
        }
    }
 }
```

## Keep in mind:

1. PHP is CaSe sEnsiTiVE, so read the documentations carefully.
2. class names should begin with Upper case letter.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was it. My only problem anymore is, that I get an Persistence Collection when I call user->getRoles() and not the ArrayCollection. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: That's fine. Doctrine uses PersistentCollection for lazy loading entities.